# jQuery AJAX TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make an AJAX request when submitting a form, but I cannot even see the request in the Network panel because **it fails before hitting the URL**. This is the code:

```
// contact form
$(function() {
    $(document).on("submit", "#contact-form", function(e) {
        // prevents normal submit
        e.preventDefault();

        var form = $(this);
        var url = form.attr("action");
        $.post(url, function(data) {
            alert(data);
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown); // TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined
        });
    });
})
```

And this is the HTML:

This is the HTML:

```
<form name="contact" method="post" action="/app_dev.php/contacts/submit" id="contact-form">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-6 form-group">
         <input type="text" id="contact_firstname" name="contact[firstname]" maxlength="255" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Entre ton nom*" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-6 form-group">
         <input type="text" id="contact_lastname" name="contact[lastname]" required="required" maxlength="255" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Entre ton nom de famille*" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-6 form-group">
         <input type="email" id="contact_email" name="contact[email]" required="required" maxlength="255" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Entre ton adresse e-mail*" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-6 form-group">
         <input type="text" id="contact_subject" name="contact[subject]" required="required" maxlength="255" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Entre le sujet*" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 mb-5">
         <textarea id="contact_message" name="contact[message]" required="required" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Écris ton message*"></textarea>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="Su1QsqB8LZdqqVRxrxBPeXQNpp29QlYEt7yvg13hzCI">
      <div class="col-xl-3">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl btn-block">Envoyer</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

I always receive an alert with this message: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined`.

If I try to put **the same code outside of the submit** (in the document ready event) it **works fine**:

```
// contact form
$(function() {
    //$(document).on("submit", "#contact-form", function(e) {
        //// prevents normal submit
        //e.preventDefault();
    //});

    var form = $("contact-form");
    var url = form.attr("action");
    $.post(url, function(data) {
        alert(data);
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown); // WORKS FINE
    });
})
```

These are my JavaScript files:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where in your code are you trying to access the property `count`?

Comment: Unfortunately, nowhere :( All the JavaScript you see in my example is all the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems that it was a very odd bug caused by the **Symfony Web Profiler Toolbar**! Luckily a fix has been released 13 hours ago:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/releases/tag/v2.8.36

This is the issue:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/26368

[image]